# How to do a near-full desktop experience sync?

Tags: configuration, sync, configuration-management

I have two machines in two fairly distant locations that I do development on, depending on where I am. I currently use a git sync to keep the following dotfiles *manually* synced

`.irssi .ssh/config .vim .bashrc .profile .vmirc .hgrc .bash_aliases .config/ipython`

And a few accessory scripts that sort out ssh key generation and distribution to a few servers that I regularly interact with.

These are great for syncing console-style applications, but for syncing things like web browsing etc, I just LastPass.

My question is, how can I go about syncing the general desktop experience (i.e. gconf, dconf, backgrounds, compiz settings, etc) without having massive conflicts from run-time modified files?

In terms of hardware, the machines are fairly similar (dual screens, nvidia displays, 12.04.1, etc) and it's easy enough to do package syncing between the machines.

Basically wondering if anyone has any 'best practices'?

Comment: I used to use symbolic links to files in a Dropbox folder, that worked quite well. Probably you could do the same with Ubuntu One.

Comment: Dropbox / Ubuntu One is dangerous if the two machines are on at the same time, which is usually the case. Hence why I moved from DB to Git :D But thanks!